# Perl variable scoping and using the same variables in an if/else block

Tags: perl

I am trying to figure out how I can use the same variables in my if/else blocks. For example,

```
$var1
$var2
$var3

if(condition) {
...
}
else {
...
}
```

I need to access $vars1, 2, and 3 in the blocks, but I cannot. I think I have a scoping issue. I tried making them global, but I see many errors and the program doesn't run properly. What am I missing?

Here is my code. My issue is that the variables at the bottom(@varList, etc) are needed for the server because this is a script on an apache server that also uses CGI. it spits out errors like this:

```
[error] Global symbol "$questionslist" requires explicit package name at /home/megaoff/www/vi
ewquestions.dhtml line 46.\nGlobal symbol "$site" requires explicit package name at /home/megaoff/www/viewquestions.dhtm
l line 46.\nGlobal symbol "$xs" requires explicit package name at /home/megaoff/www/viewquestions.dhtml line 46.\nGlobal
 symbol "$username" requires explicit package name at /home/megaoff/www/viewquestions.dhtml line 46.\n

#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use CGI;
use BarryP;

my $pagev = BarryP::makeP("noextracook", 1);
my $bvga = $pagev->{'vga'};
my %vga = %$bvga;
my $cgi = CGI->new;
my $usePage = "answerquestions.html";
my $anslist = "/home/megaoff/www/limages/anslist.txt";
my $unanslist = "/home/megaoff/www/limages/unanslist.txt";

my $action = $vga{"action"};


if($action eq 'adminmode') {
    my @a_list = $pagev->listFile($anslist);
    my %list = map { split(/\t/, $_, 2) } @a_list;
}   
else {
    my @u_list = $pagev->listFile($unanslist);
    chomp @u_list;
    my %questions = map { $_ => '' } @u_list;
    my $question = $cgi->param('question');
    my $answer = $cgi->param('answer');
    chomp($question, $answer);

    open(my $ANS, '>>', $anslist) or die "Can't open file $anslist: $!";
    print $ANS "$question\t$answer\n";
    close($ANS) or die "Can't close file $anslist: $!";

    delete $questions{$question};
    open(my $UNANS, '>', $unanslist) or die "Can't open file $unanslist: $!";
    print $UNANS "$_\n" foreach keys %questions;
    close($UNANS) or die "Can't close file $unanslist: $!";

    my $questionslist = join("<br>", @u_list);
    my $site = $pagev->{'site'};
    my $xs = $pagev->{'xs'};
    my $username = $pagev->{'username'};
}

my @varList = ('questionslist', $questionslist, 'action', $action, 'site', $site, 'xs', $xs, '$username', $username);

$pagev->pageHeader($usePage, @varList);
```

Comment: The "code example" you gave doesn't tell anything. Please provide something more meaningful, i.e. code you are working with in order to let us help you.

Comment: In the example you've shown, all three of the variables would be in scope.

Comment: Will do, gimme a few seconds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your issue is with scoping.  On line 46 when you're referencing $questionlist et al, they've already fallen out of scope because you defined them in the else block.

You have (simplified):

```
if ($blah) {
  # do stuff
} else {
  # do other stuff
  my $variable = "something";
}

doSomethingWith($variable); # illegal, $variable is not in scope.
```

`$variable` isn't defined outside of the else block, and the else block might not even be executed.  You either need to put the function in the else block, or find some way to give those variables default values, and declare them before the if statement.

Comment: I need them to be accessible to both if/else blocks. How would I do that? EDIT: Actually, would doing
my ($var1, $var2, $etc) work? Declare them as a list before I even use them?

Comment: I did this:
my ($questionslist, $action, $site, $xs, $username);
it appears to work well now! Thanks for the help.

Comment: You might find that you need to also remove the `my` keyword from the assignments of `$questionslist` et al in the else block for it to work as you expect.  And I'm not sure what behavior you want if adminmode is enabled, so test that too.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I know what I need it to do, but I just put in some trivial things so I could test and make sure that the if/else executes properly.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, your variable declarations should have the tightest scope possible while still being in scope of the code that need to access the variables.

```
my $var1 = 'aBcD';
my $var2;
if ($uc) {
   $var2 = uc($var1);
}
else {
   $var2 = lc($var1);
}
```

Of course, that could be written

```
my $var1 = 'aBcD';
my $var2 = $uc ? uc($var1) : lc($var1);
```